# I have being trying to build a new briefcase on BeeWere and at the end of it I encounter de error:

Tags: windows, beeware

Generating a new application 'IMC'
Using app template: https://github.com/beeware/briefcase-template, branch v0.3.14
Using existing template (sha be60e3889a819b0f9b547a21e803342f79cb868e, updated Wed Apr 12 11:07:29 2023)

Log saved to D:\Disck_D\App_Python\FisrtApp\logs\briefcase.2023_07_06-22_49_40.new.log

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 198, in *run_module_as_main
File "", line 88, in *run_code
File "D:\Disck_D\App_Python\FisrtApp\beeware-venv\Scripts\briefcase.exe_*main**.py", line 7, in 
File "D:\Disck_D\App_Python\FisrtApp\beeware-venv\Lib\site-packages\briefcase_*main**.py", line 25, in main
command(**options)
File "D:\Disck_D\App_Python\FisrtApp\beeware-venv\Lib\site-packages\briefcase\commands\new.py", line 529, in **call**
return self.new_app(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "D:\Disck_D\App_Python\FisrtApp\beeware-venv\Lib\site-packages\briefcase\commands\new.py", line 478, in new_app
self.generate_template(
File "D:\Disck_D\App_Python\FisrtApp\beeware-venv\Lib\site-packages\briefcase\commands\base.py", line 835, in generate_template
self.tools.cookiecutter(
File "D:\Disck_D\App_Python\FisrtApp\beeware-venv\Lib\site-packages\cookiecutter\main.py", line 116, in cookiecutter
).group(1)
^^^^^
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

I folled the tutorial on https://docs.beeware.org/en/latest/tutorial/tutorial-0.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was caused by an incompatible change in yesterday's release of cookiecutter (https://github.com/beeware/briefcase/issues/1347), which has now been fixed in Briefcase 0.3.15.

If you must use an older Briefcase version, you can work around it by installing cookiecutter version 2.1.1.

Answer (score 0):

To work around this until Briefcase v0.3.15 is released, run this command after installing Briefcase:

python -m pip install cookiecutter==2.1.1